# What is difference between string, list and list of string in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

What is difference between string, list and list of string  in cloudformation?

When I'm provision NonKeyAttributes in dynamodb using if condition.
I got Value of property NonKeyAttributes must be of type List of String when i'm trying to provising new condition z with if condition.
Also is there a better way to do this instead of too many if conditions

Conditions:
x: !Or [ !Equals [ !Ref env, "prod" ], !Equals [ !Ref env, "acpt" ] ]
y: !Or [ !Equals [ !Ref env, "infrastructure" ], !Equals [ !Ref env, "cont" ] ]
z: !Or [ !Equals [ !Ref env, "dev" ], !Equals [ !Ref env, "test" ], [ !Ref env, "prod" ], !Equals [ !Ref env, "cont" ] ]

```
Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
Properties:
  TableName: Employer
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: "empID"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "TeamID"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "Date"
      AttributeType: "N"
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "empID"
      KeyType: "HASH"
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 20
    WriteCapacityUnits: 20
  StreamSpecification: 
    StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
  PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
    PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: "ByTeamID"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "TeamID"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      - AttributeName: "Date"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      Projection:
        NonKeyAttributes:
          - "A"
          - "B"
          - "C"
          - "D"
          - !If [x, "x1", !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
          - !If [y, "y1", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
          - !If 
              - z
              - - "z1"
              - - "z2"
              - - "z3"
              - - "z4"
              - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Comment: Are you trying to only project attributes in certain cases, or is it that the attributes will only exist in certain cases? In other words, are you saying only project X if some condition is true, or is it that X will only exist if some condition is true, so you don't want to include it?

Comment: if x condition is true then it will provision x1 value. I was able to do if it has single value when condition satisfies. But for z condition i have more than value z1, z2, z3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to only project an attribute when a condition is true, and there are multiple attributes to include for a particular condition, then you'll have to repeat the `!If` for each.

```
Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
Properties:
  TableName: Employer
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: "empID"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "TeamID"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "Date"
      AttributeType: "N"
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "empID"
      KeyType: "HASH"
  ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 20
    WriteCapacityUnits: 20
  StreamSpecification: 
    StreamViewType: NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
  PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
    PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: "ByTeamID"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "TeamID"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      - AttributeName: "Date"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
      Projection:
        NonKeyAttributes:
          - "A"
          - "B"
          - "C"
          - "D"
          - !If [x, "x1", !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
          - !If [y, "y1", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
          - !If [z, "z1", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
          - !If [z, "z2", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
          - !If [z, "z3", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
          - !If [z, "z4", !Ref "AWS::NoValue" ]
```

Comment: I did like this and it worked. But is there is any other way to write to avoid multiple repeat if conditions ?

Comment: Not that I can think of. I'll be honest, I've never considered the projection to be something I might do conditions on. If the data is different I'd just include all the variants. I don't think it would care if an attribute isn't in the data. If you really want a value that is always in the data to be in the GSI conditionally then I think you have to do this.